# Connect iPod touch (client) with a linux PC (server) via wi-fi?

Tags: linux, network-programming, ipod-touch

I am developing an App for the iPod Touch 4G with iOS 4.3.3 with the aim to connect to a linux pc and exchange data: from the ipod to the pc the accel/gyro info and from the pc to the ipod frames from the webcam. Can anyone help me with some code, info, point me to ebooks or whatever..? 
I've done some stuff with the ios code already, and this is the only piece of the puzzle missing..
I am kinda desperate, i've searched everywhere and couldn't find examples (i am so not a networks/ios guru.. :/)
best regards,
Filipe Nunes

Comment: hum.. ok so i got to transfer a string from the ipod to the server in the PC. for the ipod code i followed these guides: [link](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43551/0/page/1), [link](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43551/0/page/2) and this [link](http://dev.im.ethz.ch/wiki/Socket_communication_on_the_iPhone). For the Server i used pretty straightforward the server.c (and client.c for some tests before i could connect the ipod) from this site: [link](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/c_c++/socket.htm). This site has all the info u need :) hope this can help someone as lost as i was!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this [link](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43551/0/page/1) (and the page 2)  for the iOS client programming (info for server presented as well). Follow [this link](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/c_c++/socket.htm) to create the server.c (and client.c if you need it as well). It has all the info (+files) you need.